# ascii vs asciz vs string in gas

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

What is the difference between `.ascii`, `.asciz`, and .`string` in gas? It seems clear to me that:

- `.ascii` is something like `char[]`, so `.ascii "hello"` would translate to `0x48` `0x65` `0x6c`, `0x6c`, `0x6f`.
- `.asciz` is the same but adds a `nul` to the end, so `.asciz "hello"` would translate to `0x48` `0x65` `0x6c`, `0x6c`, `0x6f` `0x00`.

But then what is the difference of `.string` vs. the two above and why would one be used over the other?

Comment: `.string` is usually the same as `.asciz`. The manual says _"Unless otherwise specified for a particular machine"_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GAS has multiple aliases for various directives for compatibility with Unix assemblers on various platforms.  This is the primary reason for redundant directives for the same thing.

Some of those aliases mean different things depending on the target platform; generally avoid those when there's a same-everywhere way, e.g. always use `.balign` or `.p2align`, never `.align`.  Always use `.ascii` or `.asciz`, never `.string`.

That way you (and future readers of your code) can just look up what it means in the GAS manual, without having to check on which way it behaves for some specific target platform.

---

As [documented in the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/String.html) for `.string` (which you should read in future when you're wondering about other directives):

> Unless otherwise specified for a particular machine, the assembler marks the end of each string with a 0 byte.

So on most targets, it's a synonym for `.asciz`.  But apparently on some, it's a synonym for `.ascii`.

There are `.string16`, `.string32`, and `.string64` directives in case you want strings of wide characters.  In that case maybe worth putting up with the possible ambiguity of zero-termination, as long as you know what it does on the ISA you're actually targeting with this source file.  I don't think there are equivalents for `asciz`.